# Find nearest (lower) value from col B after matching col A

Tags: excel, lookup

I have data as follows

SHEET 1:

```
A     B      
K01   0.5
K01   0.8
K02   0.6
K03   0.6
....
```

I need to get the lowest nearest value from col B, where I supply col A and the nearest (higher) value to match from col B.

For example: if the supplied values are var1 = 'K01' and var2 = '0.6' then the resulting formula should return row 1 in the example above.

I am stuck with how to get this formula done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=MAX(IF(IF(A1:A4=E1,B1:B4)<=F1,IF(A1:A4=E1,B1:B4)))
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

[image]

As @barry houdini suggest in comments, you can simplify the formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A4=E1,IF(B1:B4<=F1,B1:B4)))
```

with array entry.

Comment: This version would be sufficient - `=MAX(IF(A1:A4=E1,IF(B1:B4<=F1,B1:B4)))`

Comment: sure! don't know how I've missed that:)

Answer (score 0):

Since the lookup and match functions in Excel doesn't return arrays, I believe the best way to solve this problem would be to use a user function in VBA instead.

If you insert the following code in a module in VBA, it should make you able to return the value from column B as described in your question.

```vb
Function ReturnNearest(ColA As Range, ColB As Range, Var1 As Variant, Var2 As Variant)
    Dim LookupArr()
    Dim i As Integer, ArrCount As Integer
    ArrCount = 0

    'Fills array with all valid solutions
    For i = 1 To ColA.Rows.Count
        If ColA.Cells(i, 1).Value = Var1 Then
            If ColB.Cells(i, 1).Value <= Var2 Then
                ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve LookupArr(1 To ArrCount)
                LookupArr(ArrCount) = ColB.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'Finds the largest value of the possible solutions
    ReturnNearest = WorksheetFunction.Max(LookupArr)
End Function
```

Assuming you got your data in column `A` and `B` and your lookup values in cells `E3` (Var1) and `E4` (Var2), you can then use the following function to return the largest (nearest) value from column `B` based on the described criteria.

```
=ReturnNearest(A2:A5,B2:B5,E3,E4)
```